# jQuery: How to access locally scoped functions across files

Tags: jquery, scope

I have two JS files that are both wrapped in:

```
(function($) {})(jQuery)
```

and I would like to access the functions in one from the other.  I can't figure out how to do this other than removing the wrapper from one file.  Like so:

http://pastie.org/5664519

When I do this, I get "Uncaught ReferenceError: switchPlaces is not defined".  I understand why, but I don't know how to address it.

Comment: You can't do it and those functions are intentionally private, so you're not even supposed to be able to call them externally.

Comment: in example shown... the named functions shown don't need to be wrapped.

Comment: The example shown is simplified. In practice it has code that would conflict with another, conflicting use of $